# add contours labels(direct.labels) based on an existing map using qqmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to overlay several layers on a map generated by qqmap, first layer is contour line of elevation, second layer is several points I want to add, last I want to add direct labels of contour line number instead of filling with levels of color.

My code is:

```
   p0<-ggmap(ger.map)
   v <-p0+stat_contour(data=df1, aes(x=Long, y=Lati, z = elev,colour=..level..),
       inherit.aes=FALSE)+
   geom_point(data=po1, inherit.aes=FALSE,aes(x=lo, y=la),color=col,size=4,)

   direct.label(v)
```

It works well without command `direct.label`, but when I want to add the contour line labels, it pops up the error:

> Error in data.frame(x = c(6, 15), y = c(45, 55), PANEL = c(1L, 1L, 1L, : 
>           arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1195

To help you understand the error message, there are 1195 rows in data=df1,(the colnames are "x","y","Long","Lati","elev")and there are 167 rows in data=po1(colnames are just longitude and latitude). The data is converted to long format after interpolation. I guess this shouldn't be data's problem because without adding label command, I can plot out the map. But I am not 100% sure my thinking is right.

When I try this(If I removed the basic map generated by 'ggmap' shown below. It works well without error.):

```
        v <-ggplot(df1, aes(Long, Lati, z = elev))+
        stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..),size=0.9)+
        geom_point(data=po1, aes(x=lo, y=la),   color=col,inherit.aes=FALSE,size=4)

        direct.label(v)
```

But when I add `ggmap(ger.map)` in the head, it keeps giving me the same error.